# iterate through a DynamicJsonObject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, json, dynamic

I'm using a `DynamicJsonModelBinder` from a blog post to pass my JSON data from JavaScript to my ASP.NET MVC Controller as a `DynamicJsonObject`.

Have a look at the blog post: http://blog.duc.as/2011/06/07/making-mvc-3-a-little-more-dynamic/

I converted it for my project to VB.NET : http://pastebin.com/p3cfHSab.

```
Imports System.Dynamic
Imports System.Web.Helpers


Namespace MyNameSpace
    Public Class TestController

        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        Function Index(<DynamicJson()> obj As DynamicJsonObject) As ActionResult
            Dim output As String = ""
            Dim members As IEnumerable(Of String) = obj.GetDynamicMemberNames()
            For Each item In members
                output += item + vbCrLf
            Next
            Return Content(output)
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Client side:

```
 var jsonObject = { "ID": "123", "NAME": "Mr. Rosema", "TEST": "123"};
 $.ajax({
     url: "/Test",
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json",
     data:
        JSON.stringify(jsonObject)
     ,
     success: function (data) {
     }
 });
```

This works. In my controller, I can access my jsonObject like this: `obj.ID '123`

But I haven't got an idea yet how to iterate through all properties. I can get all member names as a IEnumerable String Collection (`obj.GetDynamicMemberNames()`), but how do I use the TryGetMember method to access the value of a member ?

Comment: I'm not a vb developer, but can you not access the values as a dictionary? ex `obj["ID"]`

Comment: Yes, I was wondering why accessing the values as a dictionary doesn't work although there is a private _dictionary member underlying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a class, then serialize that json into you class.

```
Class Info
    public property ID as integer
    public property NAME as string
    public property TEST as string
end class
```

Controller code:

```
Function Index(byval input as Info) As ActionResult
    Return Content(input.NAME)
End Function
```

Client side code:

```
var jsonObject = {"input": { "ID": "123", "NAME": "Mr. Rosema", "TEST": "123"}};
$.ajax({
    url: "/Test",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

Comment: That's the way how I'm currently passing my json data to the controller. But I was looking for a way to avoid having to recompile my model classes whenever my json structure changes.